# jquery hide / show for knockout foreach loop

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

inside foreach loop i have my content ...

```
                    <div foreach:"data">
             <input type="image" id="hideshow" src="/Images/aud_down-arrow.gif" />    
           <div id="content"> 
         <textarea data-bind="text:valueoftext" rows='5' cols='60'></textarea>

        </div></div>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ()     {    
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function (event)     {    
        jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
           });    
});
```

Currently it creats the text boxes but only the first text box hide/show... Rest all textboxes in the loop dont work.

Any advice on how to make this work will be great.

Comment: There is missing information in this question. Could you make the question clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, my best guess to fill in the blanks in your question is that you're generating that html in such a way that you've re-used the same id for every input and re-used the same id for every div. This results in invalid html because id must be unique on the page, and attempts to select elements by id JS/jQuery will only find the first.

What you need to do instead is give each input the same *class* attribute instead of id, and similar for the divs. It would make sense if each group of items was in its own `<li>` within a `<ul>`, or within its own `<tr>` within a `<table>`, so I suggest you do something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <input type="image" class="hideshow" src="/Images/aud_down-arrow.gif" />    
       <div class="content"> 
          <textarea data-bind="text:valueoftext" rows='5' cols='60'></textarea>
       </div>
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="image" class="hideshow" src="/Images/aud_down-arrow.gif" />    
       <div class="content"> 
          <textarea data-bind="text:valueoftext" rows='5' cols='60'></textarea>
       </div>
   </li>
   <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

Then you can use jQuery's DOM navigation methods to find the div associated with each image:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()     {    
    jQuery('.hideshow').live('click', function (event) {    
        jQuery(this).closest("li").find("div.content").toggle('show');
    });
});
```

That is, when an image is clicked, navigate up the tree to the nearest containing `<li>` (or `<tr>` or whatever you are using) and then from there navigate back down within that container to the appropriate content.

Note that `.live()` is *way* out of date and should be replaced with `.on()` - give the containing element (the `<ul>` or `<table>` or whatever you're using) an id, say `"mylist"` and then do this:

```
jQuery('#mylist').on('click', '.hideshow', function() { ...
```

If for some reason you don't have each group of elements in a container and you really don't want to add containing elements, then you still need to change the ids to classes but can then do this:

```
    jQuery('.hideshow').live('click', function (event) {    
        jQuery(this).next().toggle('show');
    });
```

I.e., select whichever element comes immediately after the clicked item and toggle it. The reason I recommend this only as a last resort is that it ties your JS closely to the structure of the html. Using the `$(this).closest("someParentElement").find("associatedElement")` type method is much more flexible and may not need to change if the html structure needs to change.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your feedback. my div is inside a forloop <div id="foreach: data"> <input type="image" class="hideshow" src="/Images/aud_down-arrow.gif" />    
       <div id="content"> 
          <textarea data-bind="text:valueoftext" rows='5' cols='60'></textarea>
       </div> I cannot have any unique Id. Please provide your feedback

Comment: _If_ you use (client-side) `id` attributes they need to be unique. If you can't make them unique for any reason then there is no point including them at all. From the html in your comment it sounds like each group of items is inside a containing `<div>`, as compared to the containing `<li>` I gave as an example in my answer. Just change my code to `...closest("div")...` instead of `...closest("li")...`. Or use the three lines of code at the end of my answer...

Answer (score 0):

use class="content" instead of id="content"

```
jQuery('.content').toggle('show');
```

For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), if more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

See more at: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/